# Редактирование вложенных пунктов меню Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть 2-x уровневое меню, которое состоит из пунктов музыкальные инструменты, свет, звук. У пункта музыкальные инструменты имеются свои пункты(гитары,духовые). Подскажите, как редактировать вложенные пункты меню(менять их порядок, изменять ссылки)?

Comment: Нашёл файл .left.menu.php, в котором есть массив для редактирования ссылок, но есть ли какой нибудь другой способ редактирования вложенных пуктов меню, через админку например?

Comment: Открыть этот же файл в админке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте! 
Если у вас используется ручное создание меню
(без пункта в настройках компонента  "Подключать файлы с именами вида .тип_меню.menu_ext.php" )

То редактирование пунктов происходит либо в публичной части сайта в режиме правки, либо в админке в вашем случае файла  .left.menu.php

А если это разделы инфоблока и вы хотите что бы меню генерировалось автоматически, Вам следует включить опцию "Подключать файлы с именами вида .тип_меню.menu_ext.php" и в файле .left.menu_ext.php указать символьный код вашего инфоблока с разделами.
Пример:

```
 <?
if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();

global $APPLICATION;

if (!function_exists("GetTreeRecursive")) //Include from main.map component
{
$aMenuLinksExt=$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:eshop.menu.sections", "", array(
    "IBLOCK_TYPE_ID" => "catalog", // Символьный код вашего Инфоблока
    "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
    "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000"
    ),
    false,
    Array('HIDE_ICONS' => 'Y')
);
$aMenuLinks = array_merge($aMenuLinks, $aMenuLinksExt);
}
?>
```

Comment: компонент eshop.menu.sections не всегда присутвует, не все же ставят демо данные